# wordpress 4.1 javascript stopped working

Tags: javascript

I have this banner image rotater using javascript which stopped working after wp 4.1 update.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgs2 = new Array("http://www.chinasurfreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/LRG-BANNER.jpg","http://www.chinasurfreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/thehundreds2.jpg");
var lnks2 = new Array("http://www.bluehawaiisurf.com.cn/","http://www.bluehawaiisurf.com.cn/");
var alt2 = new Array("lrg-banner","the-hundreds-banner");
var currentAd2 = 0;
var imgCt2 = 2;
function cycle2() {
  if (currentAd2 == imgCt2) {
    currentAd2 = 0;
  }
var banner2 = document.getElementById('adBanner2');
var link2 = document.getElementById('adLink2');
  banner2.src=imgs2[currentAd2]
  banner2.alt=alt2[currentAd2]
  document.getElementById('adLink2').href=lnks2[currentAd2]
  currentAd2++;
}
  window.setInterval("cycle2()",20000);
</script>
<a href="http://www.bluehawaiisurf.com.cn/" id="adLink2" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.chinasurfreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/LRG-BANNER.jpg" id="adBanner2" border="0" width="325" height="724"></a>
```

When I "inspect element" in chrome it says

```
script {
display: none;
}
```

And I can't change that. I'm expecting a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

haha bloody installed a new chrome extension adblock plus which removes it. *DOH!*